# When will denied IP allowed back in IIS (Deny IP Address based on the number of concurrent requests)?

Tags: asp.net, iis, sharepoint-2013, iis-8

Environment: IIS8

We have recently enabled the settings 'Deny IP Address based on the number of concurrent requests' under 'IP Address and Domain Restrictions' with the value of 100.

Currently, the IPs were blocked. When will it be allowed back?

Need an application pool recycle? or Is there any specific time gap, we can configure?

Comment: It will not block the ip address. It will just deny more than 100 requests per second. 100 rps will still be served.

Comment: Oh, Which means from the 2nd second IIS will still process another 100 requests from the same IP ? and consecutively for 3rd,4th...?

Comment: yes. for ex i make 101 requests in 1st second. It will serve the first 100 and block 101th req. in the 2nd second, i make 100 requests. It will serve all 100 of them and so on for next seconds.